# Convert managed VB.NET project to Windows Phone 8 project

Tags: converters, managed, windows-phone-8

So, I am totally new to Windows Phone. My enquiry is very general. There are a lot of good API:s out there on CodePlex for example. I seem to have to create a specific Class library for Windows Phone 8 in order to reference it. My question is then if it is possible to easy convert a project (from ANYCPU class library to Windows Phone) or maintain two branches in some way.

Any information or insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really all depends on what your library does. Answering the "how to convert a project" question has to be done on a case by case basis.  Of course the general "yes you can do it " applies but it all depends on what you managed code is calling.  Just like Silverlight is a subset of what you can do in WPF, the APIs available on Windows Phone is a subset of what is available on other platforms. (Which you don't specify). I would be happy to help more with more clarification.